# Count customers the first time they appear

Tags: sql, count, teradata

Hi I need to count the number of customers with subcategory=E grouped by seller (createdby). Once a customer has been counted by a seller, no other seller should be able to count that customer, eventhough a observation might exist.

Example

```
id  customerID  CreatedBy   createdate  subcategory
1   1111111111  EVAJEN      2014-03-14  E                                          
2   1111111111  MICMAD      2014-04-15  E
3   9999999999  MICMAD      2014-02-10  E`
```

Here MICMAD shouldn't get a count for id=2 since EVAJEN already made a sale to that customer. Right now my code looks like this, but I'm not able to check if a customer already has been counted.

```
sel createdby, cast(createdate  as date) as date1, count(distinct customerID)
from MyDatabase
where  subcategory='E' 
group by 1,2`
```

Thank you

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get the first date and count that.  In most databases (including Teradata), you can use window functions to get the first row for each customer:

```
select createdby, cast(createdate as date) as date1, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerId order by createddate asc) as seqnum 
      from MyDatabase t
      where subcategory = 'E' 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by createdby, cast(createdate as date) ;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be row_number() over (partition by customerId order by createddate **ASC**)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to get one row per customer:

```
select createdby, cast(createdate as date) as date1, count(*)
from
 (
   select *
   from tab
   where subcategory = 'E' 
   qualify row_number() -- 1st row per customer
           over (partition by customerId 
                 order by createddate) = 1 
     ) t
group by 1,2;
```